# Not able to install tm package in R Studio in Fedora-25

Tags: r, libxml2, tm

[image]

I am getting this error and i have tried  every other solution related to this given on stackoverflow but still not able to install the package.Please suggest a solution.And how can i install any R package using source on linux?

Comment: i tried using sudo dnf install libxml2-devel.But still the same error.Is there any other way i can add xml2?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong about this being a system library. Try: `install.packages('xml2', repo="https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/", dependencies=TRUE)` . I'm pretty sure you will not need `source=TRUE` since I believe that is the default for Linuxen.

Comment: Isn't this indicating missing `libiconv.so.2` instead of `xml.so`? In that case, wouldn't you need something like `yum install libiconv`? (I'm not a redhat user, just guessing.) Perhaps a better question: are you sure `libiconv.so.2` is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

In shell:

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install glibc-common
sudo yum install -y rpm-build make wget tar libxml2-devel
```

In R:

```
install.packages('xml2')
```

Instructions are adapted from https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu-server/tree/master/rpm#readme

Please let me know if it works.